# Unable to run on Apache Tez

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-tez, bigdata

Thanks for publishing this in detail with the screenshots as well.I have followed the same steps which you have mentioned, but I am not able to install properly.The error that I am encountering is

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster

I have downloaded the build version of tez. Apache Tez Version:0.8.4, Hadoop Version:2.6.0.

My tez-site.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
    <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
    <value>${fs.defaultFS}/apps/tez-0.8.4,${fs.defaultFS}/apps/tez-0.8.4/lib/</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

and my bashrc configuration is:

```
    export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
    export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
    export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
    export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
    export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
    export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
    export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin
    export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
    export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Hadoop/lib/*:.
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.
    export DERBY_HOME=/usr/local/derby
    export PATH=$PATH:$DERBY_HOME/bin
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar
    export HIVE_OPTS="-hiveconf mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 -hiveconf mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=5120"
    export TEZ_HOME=/usr/local/apache-tez-0.8.4-bin
    export TEZ_CONF_DIR=$TEZ_HOME/conf
    export TEZ_JARS=$TEZ_HOME

    if [ -z "$HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH" ]; then
    export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH="$TEZ_JARS"
    else
    export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH="$HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH:$TEZ_JARS"
    fi

    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${TEZ_CONF_DIR}:${TEZ_JARS}/*:${TEZ_JARS}/lib/*
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:${TEZ_CONF_DIR}:${TEZ_JARS}/*:${TEZ_JARS}/lib/*:.
```

my mapreduce-site.xml is

```
    <configuration>
       <!--<property>
          <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
          <value>yarn</value>
       </property> -->
       <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn-tez</value>
        <description>The runtime framework for executing MapReduce jobs.
                Can be one of local, classic or yarn.
        </description>
        </property>
    </configuration>
```

When i try to run the sample example program it is returning the trace as

```
    Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
    16/07/27 12:52:00 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
    16/07/27 12:52:00 INFO client.DAGClientImpl: DAG completed. FinalState=FAILED
    16/07/27 12:52:00 INFO examples.OrderedWordCount: DAG diagnostics: [Application application_1469604082434_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1469604082434_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
    For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://AnalyticsLinux.tcs.com:8088/proxy/application_1469604082434_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
    Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
    Container id: container_1469604082434_0001_02_000001
    Exit code: 1
    Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When i see in the http://localhost:8088 under stderr I found the above one.

Please help me in resolving this.Thanks in Advance!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Tez is an incubator project, we need to download the src and build using maven.

Detailed steps for the Tez 0.8.1 alpha version can be referred from the below link.

https://acadgild.com/blog/integrating-apache-tez-with-hadoop/

While building it will fail at tez-ui.Inorder not to face that issue, install git, node js and npm in your linux machine and then start building which will allow you to build successfully.

In addition to the mentioned steps, you need to add the parameters in the ~/.bashrc file as well

```
 export TEZ_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/tez/conf
 export TEZ_JARS=/usr/local/tez/tez
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${TEZ_CONF_DIR}:${TEZ_JARS}/*:${TEZ_JARS}/lib/*:${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:${JAVA_JDBC_LIBS}:${MAPREDUCE_LIBS}
 export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:${TEZ_CONF_DIR}:${TEZ_JARS}/*:${TEZ_JARS}/lib/*
```

Then try to run any mapreduce job which it works successfully.

Answer (score 1):

you input wrong tez package into the hdfs .

hdfs dfs -mkdir /application/tez-0.8.4

tar -zxvf apache-tez-0.8.4-bin.tar.gz

hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal apache-tez-0.8.4-bin/share/tez.tar.gz /application/tez-0.8.4